# How to retrieve the list of maven module changed between two commits in git

Tags: git, maven

I got a maven project with a main module and multiple submodule. I would like to know if there is a simple way to retrieve all the modules changed between two commits.

Answer (score 2):

For what it worth, almost 3 years after the question:

I designed on a heuristic based on git diff, based on the fact that maven artifacts are ruled by convention.

1. Extract all files changes with `git diff --name-status <commit1> <commit2>`
2. Sort out, added files, updated files and deleted files
3. From these info, if the file looks like *a/b/src/main/...* or *c/src/test*, by maven convention, impacted modules are *a/b* and *c*. If the file looks like *d/e/pom.xml*, easy! the module is *d/e*.

Of course, this cannot handle changes such as *a/b/c/README.md*. Is it in a, a/b or a/b/c ?

I use this heuristic to list all modules to recompile for CI builds. If one of the files could not be classified by the above algorithm, I just rebuild the whole project.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`git diff <commit1> <commit2> -- **/pom.xml *.pom.xml` will give you the changes that affected the main module pom file and submodules.

Comment: Thanks, but if some files of the module are modified, but not the pom, the module will not be in the resulted list I think.

Comment: so you want a tool that would map changes in the sources to the structure of the maven submodules? Doesn't your IDE show you changes in the filesystem this way?